# Weird issue date printing correctly in php but inserting into database as -2017

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Finaly managed to get insert to work
but now I cant get the date to insert correctly into the DB 
all the columns in the DB are text
Ive tried changing the column names

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else{
  echo "Connected";
  echo "<br>";
}

$Table = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM TBL_TimeDate");

while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){
    echo "Date: " . $Row['DMY'] . " | Time: " . $Row['Time'];
    echo "<BR>";
}


$Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table);


$DMY = date("d-m-Y"); 
$Time = time();

echo "Date: " . $DMY . " | Time: " . $Time;


if(!mysqli_query($DB, "INSERT INTO TBL_TimeDate (DMY, Time)
VALUES ($DMY, $Time)"))
{
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($DB));

}

?>
```

output looks like:

Date: -2017 | Time: 1412681153

Date: -2017 | Time: 1412681230

Date: -2017 | Time: 1412681231

Date: 07-10-2014 | Time: 1412681709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `$DMY` within quotes.

```
"INSERT INTO TBL_TimeDate (DMY, Time) VALUES ('$DMY', $Time)"
```

> Note:
>
> For database queries, single quotes should be used for string values.
>   MySQL also expects DATE and DATETIME literal values to be
>   single-quoted as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timestamp function in mysql server instead using date and time function in php.

*timestamp* not null default *current_timestamp*

while selecting you can explode the column data (separate the date and time using php )

Comment: Im not really looking for the most efficient way just trying things out